# Styling the aggregation rows in an ag-grid tree data grid

Tags: css, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I have an ag-grid grid (built in react) which uses the tree data format (https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/tree-data/#tree-data-aggregation).

Each row contains numeric data and the grouping rows show the sum aggregation of that data.

This is fine but I would like to highlight the aggregated values - say by making them a bolder font weight.

I have looked at the documentation for row styling but the conditional styling it refers to refers to is by value in the cell, which is not what I'm looking for (https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/row-styles/).

How can I determine if a row is from the original row data or is generated by the aggregation and style it appropriately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rowNode has `uiLevel` property. You can use it to identify top-level rows.

```js
<AgGridReact
  ...

  treeData={true}

  ...

  getRowStyle={params => {
    if (params.node.uiLevel === 0) {
        return { fontWeight: 'bold', background: '#eee' };
    }
  }}

/>
```